# Operador Ternário, is_array, inesperado

Tags: php, operadores

Veja só..
Segue a instrução

```
$var = 123;

echo "valor de var: " . is_array($var) ? implode("-",$var) : $var;
```

Ai dá o seguinte erro: `implode(): Invalid arguments passed`.

Eu esperava que não fosse executada a função de implode, já que `$var` não é array, porquê disso?

Seria algum comportamento especifico deste operador ternário?

Comment: Pelo seu código `$var` não é um array.

Comment: e não é mesmo. mas $var pode ser um array, e se ele não for eu espero somente que ele seja adicionado, se for, que se faça um implode. Este não é o propósito que minha expressão exerce? @rray

Comment: Acho que o problema aí é quanto a utilização do ternário no `echo`. Se vc fizer assim: `$var = 123;

$var2 = is_array($var) ? implode("-", $var) : $var;

echo $var2;` funciona....

Comment: Parece que a string `'valor de var` torna a expressão como `true`, teste isso: `echo "valor de var: ". false ? implode("-", $var) : $var;` tem outro coisa o php utiliza left assign no ternario, que sinigica :P alguns resultados inesperados em alguns casos. Se isola com parenteses funciona, como vc espera `echo "valor de var: ". (is_array($var) ? implode("-", $var) : $var);`

Comment: eu apenas isolei a expressão ternária, ficou algo como: `(is_array($var) ? implode("-",$var) : $var)` e funcionou como esperado, acho que compreendi o que tu disse! muito bom.. @rray, grato.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus, tem mais um exemplos, vou tentar responder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O PHP está interpretando sua expressão como true, porquê string não vazia(`true`) é avaliada como verdadeira e concatenada com algo(retorno de `is_array()`) que não faz diferença nenhuma, veja no segundo exemplo.

**Exemplo 1 - string definindo o resultado como true.**

```
$var = 123;
echo "valor de var: ". is_array($var) ? implode("-", $var) : $var); //executa o implode()
     ^                              ^  
     |                              |
inicio expressão              fim da expressão
```

**Exemplo 2 - A mesma coisa do primeiro**

```
var_dump((bool)"valor de var: ". false); //string(1) "1" 
echo "valor de var: ". false ? implode("-", $var) : $var; //executa o implode() ...
```

**Exemplo 3 - String avaliada como false**

```
var_dump((bool)"0". false);// string(0) ""
echo "0". is_array($var) ? implode("-", $var) : $var;
echo "0". false ? implode("-", $var) : $var;
```

**Exemplo 4 - resultado esperado**

Se realmente deseja utilizar o ternario com o echo, adicione parenteses nele, assim esse pedaço será analisado primeiro. O idela é não utilizar o echo e deixar o ternario sozinho.

```
echo 'valor de var: '.(is_array($var)? implode('-',$var) : $var);
$var = is_array($var) ? implode('-',$var) : $var;

echo 'valor de var: '. (is_array($var)? implode('-',$var) : $var);
     ^               ^ ^                                        ^
     |Segunda parte  | |   Essa parte é processada primeiro     |
```

Vale lembrar o PHP utiliza left side assignment para avaliar instruções ternarias.

O PHP define alguns valores que serão interpretados como `false`, o que estiver fora da lista abaixo é considerado `true`.

```
the boolean FALSE itself
the integer 0 (zero)
the float 0.0 (zero)
the empty string, and the string "0"
an array with zero elements
an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
the special type NULL (including unset variables)
SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Manual - boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

[Manual - comparação ternaria](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

[Manual - precedência de operadores](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.precedence.php)

[SOen - Understanding nested PHP ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6224330/1342547)

[SOen - PHP ternary operator not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14214427/1342547)

Comment: Amanha eu termino a resposta haha ta tarde já xD, faltou explicar como resolver

Answer (score 4):

Apenas delimite a operação ternária com parênteses.

Exemplo:

```
$var = 123;

echo 'valor de var: '.(is_array($var)? implode('-',$var) : $var);
```